# Solution to out of memory problem when recording from video device in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, video-capture, video-processing

I am receiving input from a video input device and successfully outputting to a System.Windows.Controls.Image in my WPF form. I want to record the received video and save it to disc. I have gone about this thus:

- created a class that stores A BitmapImage and the time that it was taken for each frame outputted to the screen. The BitmapImage is created from the BitmapSource created directly from the video input
- I have a list of the above class, each time that a new frame is received, I construct such a class and add it to the list
- when I come to save it, I use Splicer to construct a WMV, then save it to disc

The problem is that after about 10ish seconds (~400 frames) I get an OutOfMemoryException at different points whenever I run the program.

I tried to solve this problem by compressing each stored BitmapImage to png, jpeg and tiff, but this caused the frame rate to drop dramatically, and didn't actually buy me much more time.

Have I gone about this the completely wrong way? Or is there some work around or something that someone can recommend?

---

### Edit

Having been asked to paste code, here is the relevant code:
This is the class that stores the image

```
    public class ImageVideoFrame
    {
        private System.Drawing.Image frame;
        private long time;

        public System.Drawing.Image Frame
        {
            get { return frame; }
        }

        public long Time
        {
            get { return time; }
        }

        public ImageVideoFrame(System.Drawing.Image frame, long time)
        {
            this.frame = frame;
            this.time = time;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            frame.Dispose();

        }
    }

    Bitmap GetBitmap(BitmapSource source)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(source);
        enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(source));
        enc.Save(ms);
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ms);

        ms.Close();

        return bm;
    }
```

And here is where each frame is drawn and stored:

```
public void DrawVideoFrame(PlanarImage img, System.Windows.Controls.Image dest)
        {
            // 32-bit per pixel, RGBA image
            BitmapSource tempSource  = BitmapSource.Create(img.Width, img.Height, 
            96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, img.Bits, img.Width * img.BytesPerPixel);
            dest.Source = tempSource;


            if (recordVideo)    //record video is set elsewhere
            {
                videoRecordings.Add(new ImageVideoFrame(tempSource, 
                    DateTime.Now.Ticks / 10000));

             }

        }
```

Thanks for the help guys!!

Comment: sounds like you may be leaking memory, can you paste some code?

Comment: do the math... your talking about ~500MB worth of data. this isn't going to work. Instead you need to be streaming data into some compression library like IPP or directshow and not holding references to them once you hand them off to the compressor.

Comment: That is the kind of solution I was looking for. I knew what I was doing wouldn't be the way to go about it...

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to be certain without looking at the code, but you very likely have a memory leak.

Many of the classes you are working with (Such as Image) are Disposable since they work with unmanaged resources. Make sure that you are disposing of (or using the `using(...)` statement) any disposable instances.

Comment: Thanks Ethan, the problem I do dispose the images once the user stops recording and each is added to the WMV to be saved to file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can directly save or rather append the image you get to a file on the disk. Then you can relase the image. Maybe, this is an option for you.

Comment: I did try doing that with Splicer, but again it made the frame rate really low

Answer (score 0):

You should use only one Bitmap (polling) and write to file immediately. You can't wait after user clicks on Stop button. What if program will run for 2hours or more?

Comment: I have tried this out. And is probably the option I am going to go with. the problem is that this makes the framerate drop to something like 3 a second, which is not ideal. 

The problem is the uncompressed bitmaps are 1.17 MB, which makes a lot of data 

And the gui that I am using becomes a little unresponsive due to tall the IO-bursts. I guess it is less than ideal, but it will have to do hey.

Comment: To reduce framerate drop, you can write bitmap to memory and slowly stream its content to file.

Comment: Wouldn't this just delay the inevitable OutOfMemoryException? Memory is filling up faster than it can be emptied, albeit at not such a fast rate.

Comment: As you noted, 1.17MB per frame is pretty I/O intensive and cannot be solved either way. You must reduce the amount of data taken. Every video capture app does use some type of compression.